# How can I include an object and an integer in a JSON request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am creating an object called course. The function that creates the object requires another object and an integer to be passed through the HTTP request body. To include just the object, I simply did:

```
{
    "courseName" : "sample course"
}
```

Now, I need to not only include the object but also an integer. This integer is not part of the course object, but I need it to be passed with the object in the same request. I want to do something like:

```
{
    "course" : { "courseName" : "sample course" },
    "ownerAccId" : 0000000
}
```

However, this does not work. It tells me no courseName was provided.
How can I include the object in a format where I can use it as the intended object and also include data outside the object?

Comment: can you please add the code that you read that and where is fail

Comment: Try pasting your json to [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) and you will see what your c sharp classes should look like. Without additional information on your part we cant help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

design your C# model according to json.

```
    public class Course    {
        public string courseName { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public Course course { get; set; } 
        public int ownerAccId { get; set; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help without more information on what you're doing but maybe this might help

But let's say I were trying to write an API that would allow a consumer to create a new course that contained modules where I have Course and Module entities in my DB... I might write a JSON that looks something like this

```
{ 
    "CourseID": "ComputerScience", 
    "CourseType": "Bachelor of Science", 
    "Modules": [{ 
                "ModuleId": CS001, 
                "ModuleName": "Networking 101, 
                "Credits": 5,  
            },
            { 
                "ModuleId": CS002, 
                "ModuleName": "Databases 101", 
                "Credits": 5,  
            }],
}
```

Under the hood, I'd have a database with tables. These would be represented in my code as entities.
Then I'd have consumer facing models (called DTOs) that I use to parse the requests from the consumer of the API.
Here, what I'm doing is creating a semantic structure for what I am expecting the JSON coming in to me to look like.
And that structure isn't a reflection of what's in the underlying tables. It's just a reflection of what a consumer needs to tell me about an entity and its relationships to other entities to be able to represent it in my application.
The kind of model I might use to interact with a request like the one above would be

```
public class Course
{
        [Key]
        public string CourseId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string CourseType{ get; set; }

        ...

        //This is how our model would be set up to handle a collection of (i.e. many) modules
        public ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
            = new List<Module>();
        ..
}
```

I might imagine for the above example that the underlying DB might have a Course table and a Module table and the two might be linked under the hood using a 1:N relationship.
But I can't "know" that from looking at the JSON.

Suppose I wanted to also track Faculties so I'd know which faculties manage which courses.
Then I'd have to make changes to the database itself.
I might add a Faculty entity to the database and then I might put a FacultyID foreign key in my Coure table.
This way many courses can be owned by one faculty but each course can only be managed by one faculty

But I'd also have to make changes to the consumer facing model that I use to create new courses.
I'd also have to capture information on the faculty when a consumer tries to create a new course.

So the model that I might use here to interpret the JSON might look like this

```
public class Course
{
        [Key]
        public string CourseId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Type{ get; set; }

        ...

        //This is our foreign key
        //[ForeignKey("FacultyId")]
        public string FacultyId { get; set; }
        
        //This is how our model would be set up to handle a collection of (i.e. many) modules
        public ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
            = new List<Module>();
        ..
}
```

And then with that model I would be able to handle a request like this

```
{ 
    "FacultyId: "Science and Engineering",
    "CourseID": "ComputerScience", 
    "CourseType": "Bachelor of Science", 
    "Modules": [{ 
                "ModuleId": CS001, 
                "ModuleName": "Networking 101, 
                "Credits": 5,  
            },
            { 
                "ModuleId": CS002, 
                "ModuleName": "Databases 101", 
                "Credits": 5,  
            }],
}
```

But for all this to work I'd have to handle the mapping between the consumer facing model and the db entities as well

So at the very least I hope this helps you understand the information you need to give us for us to be able to help you. We need information on the request, the models, the entities and the mapping between the entities and the models

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nested your model. you can pass both of them in a json format like below

```
{

"courseName" : "sample course",
"ownerAccId" : 0000000

}
```

More important, you have to generate your `json` according to their model, I mean if their model is not nested you don't need to make your `json` to be nested.

If you are using `.Net` framework, you can use `Newton.Soft` to serialize your model to json format.